# Connection reset by peer, errno 104 from docker container calling external API

Tags: docker, networking, openssl, containers

I have a container that connects to an external API (on the web).

The API is okay, and if I try to call a method from the host machine and call a method to retrieve data all is working well (for example usimg a CURL POST).

Inside the container, instead, the same CURL POST starts to download data but, after a while, it stopped  in the middle of download with this:

.............."Freezed":false,"Quantit* OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104

- Failed receiving HTTP2 data
- OpenSSL SSL_write: Broken pipe, errno 32
- Failed sending HTTP2 data
- Connection #0 to host piadineriat1api.informeticons.com left intact
  curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104

Now, I've try to upgrade host system, upgrade docker, changes image version. Nothing change.
I notice that receiving few datas everything works well.

What should I check? It could be also something on local network or it's only a docker issue?

Thank you in advance.